# How can I change an overloaded operator on a Moose class at runtime?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a Moose class with an overloaded stringification operator which I would actually like to change at runtime, because I need text output in different formats.

In other words, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
$obj = Class->new("a'");
$obj->formatter("A::Formatter");
print "$obj";

# prints "a'"

$obj->formatter("Another::Formatter");
print "$obj";

# prints a1
```

I would also like the formatters to be modular, so that I can encapsulate and plug in different ones without creating a giant spaghetti mess.

How should I best do this? are roles a good solution for this kind of problem? I have checked  [MooseX::Object::Pluggable](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/MooseX-Object-Pluggable-0.0013/lib/MooseX/Object/Pluggable.pm), [MooseX::Traits::Pluggable](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/MooseX-Traits-Pluggable-0.12/lib/MooseX/Traits/Pluggable.pm) and [MooseX::Traits](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/MooseX-Traits-0.12/lib/MooseX/Traits.pm) to start but need advice as this is uncharted territory for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the *overloading* at runtime, just how it's implemented. Remember, overloading can be done with a method *name* as opposed to a subref:

```
package Foo;

use Moose;

use overload q{""} => '_stringify';

has id => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 1,
);

has formatter_class => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'ClassName',
    required => 1,
);

sub _stringify {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->formatter_class()->new()->format($self);
}
```